# JOGET - Update form field through Datalist

Tags: jogetworkflow, joget

I am new in Joget. I need some help.

I have one form (CRUD). It's datalist like as below: [image]

Now, I want to update status when I will click on assign button then selected checkbox's status value will be update to **Assigned**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is set create a hyperlink against the row in datalist on that action you can either use JDBC or dormant record plugin to update status.